# Linear Transformation- Standard Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

A standard matrix is given: $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 & -3 \\ 2 & 2 & -5 \end{bmatrix}$$ representing the linear transformation $L: \mathbb{R}^3 -> \mathbb{R}^3$.

How to find $L(2,-3,1)$?

Comment: You have to learn what matrix multiplication is. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Square_matrix_and_column_vector), for instance.

Comment: I know it sounds stupid but I multiplied them but I I am still not getting the right answer.

Comment: If you know the dot product, you have to do the dot product of each `row` of $A$ with the column-vector $\;\begin{bmatrix}2\\-3\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I know. I am not even that stupid :P

Comment: What do you obtain?

Comment: [6 -4 -7] is my answer.

Comment: Max, welcome to Math Stackexchange. You'll receive more and more detailed help if you provide more information in your questions, in particular showing what you have already tried and why you are asking your question. From your comments it looks like you already tried something but it looks like the expected answer is something different. I'd suggest you provide us both, what you did, what you get and what is that answer that seems to be eluding you.

Comment: Your answer is fine. Your way of writing $A$ is by rows?

Comment: By columns. I don't know how to write as column.

Comment: W.r.t. your initial post, the new version is by rows. The answer is fine. What are you expected to find? $\;(-1 -3\enspace 10)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I think of putting a vector through a matrix is you push it down from the top then add across the sides. I will show you this approach in a general way.
$\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}ax&by&cz\\dx&ey&fz\\gx&hy&iz\end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}ax+by+cz\\dx+ey+fz\\gx+hy+iz\end{bmatrix}$. This gives you the anwser:
$\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}ax+by+cz\\dx+ey+fz\\gx+hy+iz\end{bmatrix}$.
Now for your problem plug in your values and multiply then add.

Comment: I did the same thing but I am still not getting the answer. That's why I asked it.

Comment: for my interest what answer did you get?

Comment: [6 -4 -7] is my answer.

Comment: That is what I get as well so it is likely your answer key has a typo or the person making it made a mistake. It happens from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this matrix is given with respect to the standard basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$, then the columns of the matrix are just $(L(e_1),L(e_2),L(e_3))$, respectively. Thus, $$L(e_1)=(0,1,2), \quad L(e_2)=(-1,1,2), \quad L(e_3) = (3,-3,-5).$$

Hence, $$L(2,-3,1)=L(2e_1-3e_2+e_3)=2L(e_1)-3L(e_2)+L(e_3) = (6,-4,-7).$$

Alternatively, for any vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$, the following is true: $$Lv=Av,$$ where $v=\begin{pmatrix}x \\y\\z \end{pmatrix}.$